# How to use double for matrices

Tags: java, arrays, double

This is the code I wrote:

```
public class main
{
    public static int arraySum(int[] arr)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            result += arr[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int arraySumBetter(int[] a)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for(int value : a)
        {
            result += value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 48};
        System.out.println(arraySum(a));
        System.out.println(arraySumBetter(a));
    }
}
```

When I run it, it prints:

```
58

58
```

But I want the result to be `58.0`.
I changed all the `int` into `double`:

```
public class main
{
    public static double arraySum(double[] arr)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for(double i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1)
        {
            result += arr[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int arraySumBetter(double[] a)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for(double value : a)
        {
            result += value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 48};
        System.out.println(arraySum(a));
        System.out.println(arraySumBetter(a));
    }
}
```

But it didn't compile:

```
typed.java:8: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
      result += arr[i];
                    ^

typed.java:19: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    return result;
           ^
2 errors
```

Do I need to add more code? Or something else?

Comment: Add the code with `double` variables so that we can have a look & tell the issue

Comment: Try to post exactly what's not working, this is the code before you've applied your changes.

Comment: the problem is that you also need to change `int result;` to `double result;`

Comment: Why do you want a `double` result from adding `int`(s)? I could see a `long` or `BigInteger`. But why, specifically, a `double`? Also, in Java 8+, *better still*: `int sum = IntStream.of(a).sum();`

Comment: Oh. Then in Java 8+, `double sum = DoubleStream.of(a).sum();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly sneaky one: look at this code

```
for (double i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    result += arr[i];
}
```

the variable used for **index** of the array is a double all of a sudden, but an array index is always an integral value. That's what causes the compilation error.

Revert the index variable to int and you'll be all set. That is, revert your code to

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    result += arr[i];
}
```

Note: if all you want is just a result with one decimal, the solution you choose is pretty heavy handed, calculations on doubles are slower than those on integers, and double math has its own challenges - just look around here on SO. A simple way to keep all calculations in ints but at the same time print the result with 1 decimal could be

```
System.out.format("%.1f", (double) arraySumBetter(a));
```

in that case, you'd use the first version of arraySumBetter, ie `public static int arraySumBetter(int [] a)`

Comment: than what should i do? I don't get it.. my english is pretty bad..sorry

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This answer is correct (the array index is what causes the first compilation error)

Comment: Yeah I'm always willing to learn and improve. Just an anon downvote is pretty useless.

Comment: Well if you upvoted, there are 2 anonymous downvotes. But anyways, if it helped you, great, that's what counts.

Answer (score 0):

your problem in this function `int arraySumBetter(double [] a)`

`return` value is `int` but you declared `result` in your function as `double` variable so it will be a `lossy conversion from double to int` problem when you return `result`

it should be:

```
public static double arraySumBetter(double [] a)
```

also index counter type of array should be integer value :

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) // not double i
```

you can format your output in specific floating point precision using `printf` method:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f\n",arraySum(a));
System.out.printf("%.1f\n",arraySumBetter(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an array can only be indexed using integers. This means, `arr[true]` or `arr[5.32]` is **not allowed**.

The compiler complains because it needs to convert the double to an integer value, and this would cut off the decimal places. Java never does that implicity - you have to **cast** it to an integer:

```java
double foo = 5.32;
// convert to integer:
int bar = (int) foo;
```

In your case a typecast is not necessary. If the variable `i` is of type `int`, it works fine.

In the second method, you have the wrong return type. It returns a double, but the declaration says

```
public static int arraySumBetter
```